# Jmockit Expectations/Verifications for calls to private methods when testing a public method?

Tags: jmockit

Can anyone advise if it is possible to use an expectations/verifications to test that private methods are being called the-right-number-of-times/right-parameters.

The Class under test has been Mocked-Up - with one private method overridden.

Am Testing a public method which calls into a number of private methods.

I wish to know if it is possible to verify the calls to other private methods which will be called when the public method is being executed ?

Some idea of the code/class under test;

```
public class UnderTest {

    public void methodPublic(arg 1){
        .....
        methodPrivate1(var1);
        ....
        methodPrivate2(var2);
    }

    private void methodPrivate1(var1){
        //do stuff
    }

    private void methodPrivate2(var1){
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

In my test case

```
@Test
public void stateBasedTestMethod()
{
    UnderTest underTest;

    new MockUp<UnderTest>() {
        @Mock(invocations = 1)
        private void methodPrivate2(var1) {
            //do nothing in the mocked case
        }
    };

    underTest = new UnderTest();
    underTest.methodPublic(arg1);

    new Verifications() {{
        // Is there a way to test that methodPrivate1 has been called-once/with-expected-arguments
    }};
}
```

---

Edited in response to the answer from Rogério.
I am using jmockit 1.12
and the Verifications is FAILING as the method using the provided solution is invoking the method twice as I thought from the JMockit documentation.

**Failure Trace;
mockit.internal.UnexpectedInvocation: Expected exactly 1 invocation(s) of MyHelperTest$1#method3..., but was invoked 2 time(s)**

Included is the full code I am using for this.
As described above - my goal is to mock one of the private methods to do nothing.
And ensure that I can verify that the other private method is called only once.

Thanks in advance and hopefully will get a better understanding if this is possible with Jmockit.

Test Code.

```
public class MyHelperTest {

    @Test
    public void testHelper(@Mocked final MyDependent myDependent) {

        final MyHelper myHelper;

        new MockUp<MyHelper>() {

            @Mock(invocations = 1)
            private void method3(MyDependent myTable) {
                System.out.println("In Mocked Method");
                //do nothing in the mocked case
            }

        };

        myHelper = new MyHelper();

        myHelper.method1(myDependent);

        new Verifications() {{ 
            invoke(myHelper, "method2", myDependent); times = 1; 
        }};
    }

}
```

Class under test.

```
public class MyHelper {

    public void method1(MyDependent myDependent){
        method2(myDependent);
    }

    private void method2(MyDependent myDependent) {
        myDependent.setValue(1);
        method3(myDependent);
    }

    private void method3(MyDependent myDependent) {
        myDependent.setValue(2);
    }

}
```

Dependent Class

```
public class MyDependent {

    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, though not recommended to mock `private` methods.

Using the Expectations API:

```
@Tested @Mocked MyHelper myHelper;

@Test
public void testHelper(@Mocked final MyDependent myDependent)
{
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{ invoke(myHelper, "method3", myDependent); }};

    myHelper.method1(myDependent);

    new Verifications() {{ invoke(myHelper, "method2", myDependent); times = 1; }};
}
```

... where the `invoke(...)` method is statically imported from class `mockit.Deencapsulation`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The suggested solution doesn't CHECK that the invocation has occured on the private method.
Instead another invocation is made on "methodPrivate1" - confirmed through testing.

From mockit.Deencapsulation.invoke(Object, String, Object...)
"Invokes a non-accessible (eg private) instance method from a given class with the given arguments."

I am trying to ascertain;
WHETHER it is possible to CHECK the invocations (times and args) on a private methods when testing a public method.

Regarding mocking the private method this is dont to avoid DataBase writes during testing.

Comment: My example test should work with JMockit 1.12; if you're using an older version, then the test won't be so simple (@Tested + @Mocked on the same field is a new feature). It is supposed to check the invocation to the private method occurred, yes.

Comment: See above edit to the original question in response to your feedback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The updated test in the answer above is what you want (tested on JMockit 1.12).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if a method you want to verify is not mocked, when the static block in an Expectations or Verifications instance is executed that the code calls the method that you are trying to mark as expected or verify.
This might explain the extra invocation that you are seeing.

One suggestion: if you are already mocking the class with MockUp (and thus creating an anonymous subclass) so you can override the private method, why not change the access of the overridden private method to protected or public?  Then you can create an expectation or verification on it.

You could also provide a public field "public int counter=0;" and have your overridden method increment the counter.  Then you can use an assert on it after the test is complete.

Comment: I don't want to change access because the methods are not meant to be used outside of the class.  They are helper methods, meaningful only to the class.

Comment: You aren't understanding what I suggested. I didn't say change the access of the method in your class. I said make an override of your method in the anonymous subclass and give it public or protected access.